# Open mapping theorem for Frechet spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, open-map

In Conway's *Functional Analysis* textbook, exercise-IV.2.8 asks to prove the open mapping theorem for Frechet spaces. In Conway's book, a Frechet space is not required to be locally convex.

> Let $X,Y$ be Frechet spaces, and $T: X\to Y$ a surjective continuous linear map. Then $T$ is an open map.

I can mimic the proof for Banach spaces but get stuck after the step where the image of a particular open ball contains an open ball in $Y$.

*Attempted Proof.* Since, in metric spaces, the open balls are basic open sets, it suffices to show, for every $r>0$ and $x\in X$, $T(B_X(x, r))$ is open in $Y$. By the homeomorphism of translation, it then suffices to show $T(B_X(0, r))\ni 0_Y$ is open in $Y$. Since $T$ is surjective, we have
$$Y=T(X)=T(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_X(0, nr))=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}T(B_X(0, nr)).$$
Since Frechet spaces are complete metric spaces, by Baire Category Theorem, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$, such that
$\text{Int}\overline{T(B_X(0, n_0r))}\neq \emptyset,$
and so there exist $y_0\in Y$ and $r_0>0$ such that
$$B_Y(y_0, r_0)\subset \overline{T(B_X(0, n_0r))}\Rightarrow y_0, y_0+v \in \overline{T(B_X(0, n_0r))},$$
where $v\in B_Y(0, r_0)$. Hence, for every such $v$, we have
$$v\in \overline{T(B_X(0, 2n_0r))}\Rightarrow B_Y(0, r_0)\subset \overline{T(B_X(0, 2n_0r))}.$$

Next, we must show there are no holes in $T(B_X(0, 2n_0r))\cap B_Y(0, r_0)$. Same as with Banach spaces cases, we can do so by finding a series $\sum_n x_n$, whose image under $T$ converges to arbitrary point $y \in B_Y(0, r_0)$.

Note, for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $r_{0,m}>0$ such that $B_Y(0, r_{0,m})\subset \overline{T(B_X(0, \frac{2n_0r}{2^m}))}.$ This is true because we can repeat the Baire Category argument as above for every radius $\frac{2n_0r}{2^m}$. Define $\tilde{r_{0,m}}:=\min\{r_{0,m}, \frac{r_0}{2^m}\}$. Then, we have
$$B_Y(0, \tilde{r_{0,m}})\subset \overline{T(B_X(0, \frac{2n_0r}{2^m}))}.$$
Therefore, if we start from an arbitary point $y_1\in B_Y(0, r_0)$, there exist $x_1\in B_X(0, 2n_0r)$, and by induction, we can have two sequences $(x_m)$ and $(y_m)$ such that
$$x_m\in B_X(0, \frac{2n_0r}{2^m}); \quad y_{m+1}=y_m-Tx_m \in B_Y(0, \tilde{r_{0,m}})\subset B_Y(0, \frac{r_{0}}{2^m}).$$
By completeness of $X$, the series $\sum_m x_m$ then converges absolutely to some $\xi\in B_X(0, 4n_0r)$, and so $$y_{m+1}=y_m -Tx_m =y_1 -T(\sum_{i=1}^mx_i) \to 0\Rightarrow y_1=T\xi\Rightarrow B_Y(0, r_0)\subset T(B_X(0, 4n_0r)).$$

**However, I don't know how to use what I've proved so far to finally show it also works for *every* open ball, since in Frechet spaces, the metric is not homogeneous. So we can't simply multiply an arbitary scalar to make a fixed open ball cover any open ball with a different radius.**

**Update:** After consulting Rudin's textbook, it seems Baire category theorem should be applied at the following decomposition:
$$Y=T(X)=T(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} n\cdot B_X(0, r))=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}n\cdot T(B_X(0, r)).$$
Then, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$, $y_0\in Y$ and $r_0>0$ such that
$$B_Y(y_0, r_0)\subset \overline{n_0\cdot T(B_X(0, r))}=n_0\cdot\overline{ T(B_X(0, r))}.$$
Then, there exists a $r_0'\in (0, \frac{r_0}{n_0})$ such that
$$B_Y(y_0, r_0')\subset \overline{ T(B_X(0, r))}.$$
Everything can then proceed from there without obstacles.

Comment: See Open Mapping Theorem in Rudin's FA.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks. Just downloaded that book. It seems my mistake happens at how to decompose space $X$. Instead of covering all of $X$ with the union of $B_X(0, nr)$, I should've used the union of $n \cdot B_X(0, r)$, using the fact that $B_X(0, r)$ is absorbing. Then apply the Baire Cat Thm at this countable union.